# How to concat unique values in Quicksight

Tags: amazon-web-services, dashboard, amazon-quicksight

I have the following dataset

| id | timestamp | name | address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-07-11 | Joe | `['123 Fake St', '456 Fake St']` |
| 1 | 2023-07-10 | Joe | `['123 Fake St', '789 Nowhere Dr']` |
| 2 | 2023-07-11 | John | `['123 Fake St']` |

I want my final table to look like this

| id | name | records_freq | addresses |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Joe | 2 | 123 Fake St: 2 456 Fake St: 1 789 Nowhere Dr: 1 |
| 2 | John | 1 | 123 Fake St: 1 |

I have the first 3 columns working fine. I just can't figure out how to concatenate unique values afterwards and note how many times each of them occurred. In python this is pretty straightforward, but if I create a hacky table I won't be able to modify any of it based on timestamp which really matters to me.